# Border on circle creates 1px of black outline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

I'm creating a header which has a circle in the middle that flips sides. I'm using a plugin called flip.js to get the flip state of the circle in order to place content inside. One example of this content is a white text, black background with a 10px border around it. As you can see it creates a 1px "border" around the circle showing the original color. How can I fix this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIb8t.png)

here is my code:

Note: The function is defined at the bottom of the JS, I wanted to include the vendor since it might be the cause of the problem.

```js
/*! flip - v1.1.2 - 2016-10-20
* https://github.com/nnattawat/flip
* Copyright (c) 2016 Nattawat Nonsung; Licensed MIT */
(function( $ ) {
    /*
     * Private attributes and method
     */

    // Function from David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback licensed with http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
    var whichTransitionEvent = function() {
        var t, el = document.createElement("fakeelement"),
            transitions = {
                "transition"      : "transitionend",
                "OTransition"     : "oTransitionEnd",
                "MozTransition"   : "transitionend",
                "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
            };

        for (t in transitions) {
            if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
                return transitions[t];
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * Model declaration
     */
    var Flip = function($el, options, callback) {
        // Define default setting
        this.setting = {
            axis: "y",
            reverse: false,
            trigger: "click",
            speed: 500,
            forceHeight: false,
            forceWidth: false,
            autoSize: true,
            front: '.front',
            back: '.back'
        };

        this.setting = $.extend(this.setting, options);

        if (typeof options.axis === 'string' && (options.axis.toLowerCase() === 'x' || options.axis.toLowerCase() === 'y')) {
            this.setting.axis = options.axis.toLowerCase();
        }

        if (typeof options.reverse === "boolean") {
            this.setting.reverse = options.reverse;
        }

        if (typeof options.trigger === 'string') {
            this.setting.trigger = options.trigger.toLowerCase();
        }

        var speed = parseInt(options.speed);
        if (!isNaN(speed)) {
            this.setting.speed = speed;
        }

        if (typeof options.forceHeight === "boolean") {
            this.setting.forceHeight = options.forceHeight;
        }

        if (typeof options.forceWidth === "boolean") {
            this.setting.forceWidth = options.forceWidth;
        }

        if (typeof options.autoSize === "boolean") {
            this.setting.autoSize = options.autoSize;
        }

        if (typeof options.front === 'string' || options.front instanceof $) {
            this.setting.front = options.front;
        }

        if (typeof options.back === 'string' || options.back instanceof $) {
            this.setting.back = options.back;
        }

        // Other attributes
        this.element = $el;
        this.frontElement = this.getFrontElement();
        this.backElement = this.getBackElement();
        this.isFlipped = false;

        this.init(callback);
    };

    /*
     * Public methods
     */
    $.extend(Flip.prototype, {

        flipDone: function(callback) {
            var self = this;
            // Providing a nicely wrapped up callback because transform is essentially async
            self.element.one(whichTransitionEvent(), function() {
                self.element.trigger('flip:done');
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback.call(self.element);
                }
            });
        },

        flip: function(callback) {
            if (this.isFlipped) {
                return;
            }

            this.isFlipped = true;

            var rotateAxis = "rotate" + this.setting.axis;
            this.frontElement.css({
                transform: rotateAxis + (this.setting.reverse ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
                "z-index": "0"
            });

            this.backElement.css({
                transform: rotateAxis + "(0deg)",
                "z-index": "1"
            });
            this.flipDone(callback);
        },

        unflip: function(callback) {
            if (!this.isFlipped) {
                return;
            }

            this.isFlipped = false;

            var rotateAxis = "rotate" + this.setting.axis;
            this.frontElement.css({
                transform: rotateAxis + "(0deg)",
                "z-index": "1"
            });

            this.backElement.css({
                transform: rotateAxis + (this.setting.reverse ? "(180deg)" : "(-180deg)"),
                "z-index": "0"
            });
            this.flipDone(callback);
        },

        getFrontElement: function() {
            if (this.setting.front instanceof $) {
                return this.setting.front;
            } else {
                return this.element.find(this.setting.front);
            }
        },

        getBackElement: function() {
            if (this.setting.back instanceof $) {
                return this.setting.back;
            } else {
                return this.element.find(this.setting.back);
            }
        },

        init: function(callback) {
            var self = this;

            var faces = self.frontElement.add(self.backElement);
            var rotateAxis = "rotate" + self.setting.axis;
            var perspective = self.element["outer" + (rotateAxis === "rotatex" ? "Height" : "Width")]() * 2;
            var elementCss = {
                'perspective': perspective,
                'position': 'relative'
            };
            var backElementCss = {
                "transform": rotateAxis + "(" + (self.setting.reverse ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")",
                "z-index": "0",
                "position": "relative"
            };
            var faceElementCss = {
                "backface-visibility": "hidden",
                "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
                "position": "absolute",
                "z-index": "1"
            };

            if (self.setting.forceHeight) {
                faces.outerHeight(self.element.height());
            } else if (self.setting.autoSize) {
                faceElementCss.height = '100%';
            }

            if (self.setting.forceWidth) {
                faces.outerWidth(self.element.width());
            } else if (self.setting.autoSize) {
                faceElementCss.width = '100%';
            }

            // Back face always visible on Chrome #39
            if ((window.chrome || (window.Intl && Intl.v8BreakIterator)) && 'CSS' in window) {
                //Blink Engine, add preserve-3d to self.element
                elementCss["-webkit-transform-style"] = "preserve-3d";
            }


            faces.css(faceElementCss).find('*').css({
                "backface-visibility": "hidden"
            });

            self.element.css(elementCss);
            self.backElement.css(backElementCss);

            // #39
            // not forcing width/height may cause an initial flip to show up on
            // page load when we apply the style to reverse the backface...
            // To prevent self we first apply the basic styles and then give the
            // browser a moment to apply them. Only afterwards do we add the transition.
            setTimeout(function() {
                // By now the browser should have applied the styles, so the transition
                // will only affect subsequent flips.
                var speedInSec = self.setting.speed / 1000 || 0.5;
                faces.css({
                    "transition": "all " + speedInSec + "s ease-out"
                });

                // This allows flip to be called for setup with only a callback (default settings)
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback.call(self.element);
                }

                // While this used to work with a setTimeout of zero, at some point that became
                // unstable and the initial flip returned. The reason for this is unknown but we
                // will temporarily use a short delay of 20 to mitigate this issue.
            }, 20);

            self.attachEvents();
        },

        clickHandler: function(event) {
            if (!event) { event = window.event; }
            if (this.element.find($(event.target).closest('button, a, input[type="submit"]')).length) {
                return;
            }

            if (this.isFlipped) {
                this.unflip();
            } else {
                this.flip();
            }
        },

        hoverHandler: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.element.off('mouseleave.flip');

            self.flip();

            setTimeout(function() {
                self.element.on('mouseleave.flip', $.proxy(self.unflip, self));
                if (!self.element.is(":hover")) {
                    self.unflip();
                }
            }, (self.setting.speed + 150));
        },

        attachEvents: function() {
            var self = this;
            if (self.setting.trigger === "click") {
                self.element.on($.fn.tap ? "tap.flip" : "click.flip", $.proxy(self.clickHandler, self));
            } else if (self.setting.trigger === "hover") {
                self.element.on('mouseenter.flip', $.proxy(self.hoverHandler, self));
                self.element.on('mouseleave.flip', $.proxy(self.unflip, self));
            }
        },

        flipChanged: function(callback) {
            this.element.trigger('flip:change');
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback.call(this.element);
            }
        },

        changeSettings: function(options, callback) {
            var self = this;
            var changeNeeded = false;

            if (options.axis !== undefined && self.setting.axis !== options.axis.toLowerCase()) {
                self.setting.axis = options.axis.toLowerCase();
                changeNeeded = true;
            }

            if (options.reverse !== undefined && self.setting.reverse !== options.reverse) {
                self.setting.reverse = options.reverse;
                changeNeeded = true;
            }

            if (changeNeeded) {
                var faces = self.frontElement.add(self.backElement);
                var savedTrans = faces.css(["transition-property", "transition-timing-function", "transition-duration", "transition-delay"]);

                faces.css({
                    transition: "none"
                });

                // This sets up the first flip in the new direction automatically
                var rotateAxis = "rotate" + self.setting.axis;

                if (self.isFlipped) {
                    self.frontElement.css({
                        transform: rotateAxis + (self.setting.reverse ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
                        "z-index": "0"
                    });
                } else {
                    self.backElement.css({
                        transform: rotateAxis + (self.setting.reverse ? "(180deg)" : "(-180deg)"),
                        "z-index": "0"
                    });
                }
                // Providing a nicely wrapped up callback because transform is essentially async
                setTimeout(function() {
                    faces.css(savedTrans);
                    self.flipChanged(callback);
                }, 0);
            } else {
                // If we didnt have to set the axis we can just call back.
                self.flipChanged(callback);
            }
        }

    });

    /*
     * jQuery collection methods
     */
    $.fn.flip = function (options, callback) {
        if (typeof options === 'function') {
            callback = options;
        }

        if (typeof options === "string" || typeof options === "boolean") {
            this.each(function() {
                var flip = $(this).data('flip-model');

                if (options === "toggle") {
                    options = !flip.isFlipped;
                }

                if (options) {
                    flip.flip(callback);
                } else {
                    flip.unflip(callback);
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.each(function() {
                if ($(this).data('flip-model')) { // The element has been initiated, all we have to do is change applicable settings
                    var flip = $(this).data('flip-model');

                    if (options && (options.axis !== undefined || options.reverse !== undefined)) {
                        flip.changeSettings(options, callback);
                    }
                } else { // Init
                    $(this).data('flip-model', new Flip($(this), (options || {}), callback));
                }
            });
        }

        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));

InitializeHeaderSlider();

// Trigger slide every 2 seconds
function InitializeHeaderSlider() {

  var oInterval = setInterval(function() {

      // Initialize flipper
      var oFlip = $('#FlipWrapper').flip();

      // Trigger flip toggle
      oFlip.flip('toggle');
      
      
console.log('flipped');

  },2000);

}
```

```css
div#FlipWrapper {
    z-index: 999 !important;
    top: 38%;
    pointer-events: none;
    transform: translateX(-3%) skew(16deg);
    position: relative;
}

    div#FlipWrapper div.Wrapper {
        display: block;
        width: 175px !important;
        height: 175px !important;
        border: 10px solid #ffffff;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

    div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo {
        width: inherit !important;
        height: inherit !important;
        background-color: #241f20;
        position: absolute !important;
        z-index: 99;
        top: 32%;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

        div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 35px;
        }

            div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner > img {
                width: 100%;
                transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-8deg);
            }

            div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner p {
                color: #ffffff;
                transform: rotate(-12deg);
                line-height: 43px;
                text-align: center;
                display: inline;
                font-size: 52px;
                font-family: "AmaticBold", sans-serif;
                margin-left: 10px;
                margin-top: 40px;
            }

                div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner p span {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 42px;
                }
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="FlipWrapper">

  <div class="ShopLogo front">
      <div class="Wrapper">
          <div id="FlipCoinFront" class="Inner valign-wrapper">
              <p>shop <span class="In"> - in - </span>shop</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


  <div class="ShopLogo back">
      <div class="Wrapper">
          <div id="FlipCoinBack" class="Inner valign-wrapper"></div>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the background of `div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo` is showing under the border of the child `div#FlipWrapper div.Wrapper`. To fix the problem, move the `border` and `border-radius` settings to `div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo`:

```js
/*! flip - v1.1.2 - 2016-10-20
 * https://github.com/nnattawat/flip
 * Copyright (c) 2016 Nattawat Nonsung; Licensed MIT */
(function($) {
  /*
   * Private attributes and method
   */

  // Function from David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback licensed with http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
  var whichTransitionEvent = function() {
    var t, el = document.createElement("fakeelement"),
      transitions = {
        "transition": "transitionend",
        "OTransition": "oTransitionEnd",
        "MozTransition": "transitionend",
        "WebkitTransition": "webkitTransitionEnd"
      };

    for (t in transitions) {
      if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
        return transitions[t];
      }
    }
  };

  /*
   * Model declaration
   */
  var Flip = function($el, options, callback) {
    // Define default setting
    this.setting = {
      axis: "y",
      reverse: false,
      trigger: "click",
      speed: 500,
      forceHeight: false,
      forceWidth: false,
      autoSize: true,
      front: '.front',
      back: '.back'
    };

    this.setting = $.extend(this.setting, options);

    if (typeof options.axis === 'string' && (options.axis.toLowerCase() === 'x' || options.axis.toLowerCase() === 'y')) {
      this.setting.axis = options.axis.toLowerCase();
    }

    if (typeof options.reverse === "boolean") {
      this.setting.reverse = options.reverse;
    }

    if (typeof options.trigger === 'string') {
      this.setting.trigger = options.trigger.toLowerCase();
    }

    var speed = parseInt(options.speed);
    if (!isNaN(speed)) {
      this.setting.speed = speed;
    }

    if (typeof options.forceHeight === "boolean") {
      this.setting.forceHeight = options.forceHeight;
    }

    if (typeof options.forceWidth === "boolean") {
      this.setting.forceWidth = options.forceWidth;
    }

    if (typeof options.autoSize === "boolean") {
      this.setting.autoSize = options.autoSize;
    }

    if (typeof options.front === 'string' || options.front instanceof $) {
      this.setting.front = options.front;
    }

    if (typeof options.back === 'string' || options.back instanceof $) {
      this.setting.back = options.back;
    }

    // Other attributes
    this.element = $el;
    this.frontElement = this.getFrontElement();
    this.backElement = this.getBackElement();
    this.isFlipped = false;

    this.init(callback);
  };

  /*
   * Public methods
   */
  $.extend(Flip.prototype, {

    flipDone: function(callback) {
      var self = this;
      // Providing a nicely wrapped up callback because transform is essentially async
      self.element.one(whichTransitionEvent(), function() {
        self.element.trigger('flip:done');
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback.call(self.element);
        }
      });
    },

    flip: function(callback) {
      if (this.isFlipped) {
        return;
      }

      this.isFlipped = true;

      var rotateAxis = "rotate" + this.setting.axis;
      this.frontElement.css({
        transform: rotateAxis + (this.setting.reverse ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
        "z-index": "0"
      });

      this.backElement.css({
        transform: rotateAxis + "(0deg)",
        "z-index": "1"
      });
      this.flipDone(callback);
    },

    unflip: function(callback) {
      if (!this.isFlipped) {
        return;
      }

      this.isFlipped = false;

      var rotateAxis = "rotate" + this.setting.axis;
      this.frontElement.css({
        transform: rotateAxis + "(0deg)",
        "z-index": "1"
      });

      this.backElement.css({
        transform: rotateAxis + (this.setting.reverse ? "(180deg)" : "(-180deg)"),
        "z-index": "0"
      });
      this.flipDone(callback);
    },

    getFrontElement: function() {
      if (this.setting.front instanceof $) {
        return this.setting.front;
      } else {
        return this.element.find(this.setting.front);
      }
    },

    getBackElement: function() {
      if (this.setting.back instanceof $) {
        return this.setting.back;
      } else {
        return this.element.find(this.setting.back);
      }
    },

    init: function(callback) {
      var self = this;

      var faces = self.frontElement.add(self.backElement);
      var rotateAxis = "rotate" + self.setting.axis;
      var perspective = self.element["outer" + (rotateAxis === "rotatex" ? "Height" : "Width")]() * 2;
      var elementCss = {
        'perspective': perspective,
        'position': 'relative'
      };
      var backElementCss = {
        "transform": rotateAxis + "(" + (self.setting.reverse ? "180deg" : "-180deg") + ")",
        "z-index": "0",
        "position": "relative"
      };
      var faceElementCss = {
        "backface-visibility": "hidden",
        "transform-style": "preserve-3d",
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "1"
      };

      if (self.setting.forceHeight) {
        faces.outerHeight(self.element.height());
      } else if (self.setting.autoSize) {
        faceElementCss.height = '100%';
      }

      if (self.setting.forceWidth) {
        faces.outerWidth(self.element.width());
      } else if (self.setting.autoSize) {
        faceElementCss.width = '100%';
      }

      // Back face always visible on Chrome #39
      if ((window.chrome || (window.Intl && Intl.v8BreakIterator)) && 'CSS' in window) {
        //Blink Engine, add preserve-3d to self.element
        elementCss["-webkit-transform-style"] = "preserve-3d";
      }


      faces.css(faceElementCss).find('*').css({
        "backface-visibility": "hidden"
      });

      self.element.css(elementCss);
      self.backElement.css(backElementCss);

      // #39
      // not forcing width/height may cause an initial flip to show up on
      // page load when we apply the style to reverse the backface...
      // To prevent self we first apply the basic styles and then give the
      // browser a moment to apply them. Only afterwards do we add the transition.
      setTimeout(function() {
        // By now the browser should have applied the styles, so the transition
        // will only affect subsequent flips.
        var speedInSec = self.setting.speed / 1000 || 0.5;
        faces.css({
          "transition": "all " + speedInSec + "s ease-out"
        });

        // This allows flip to be called for setup with only a callback (default settings)
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          callback.call(self.element);
        }

        // While this used to work with a setTimeout of zero, at some point that became
        // unstable and the initial flip returned. The reason for this is unknown but we
        // will temporarily use a short delay of 20 to mitigate this issue.
      }, 20);

      self.attachEvents();
    },

    clickHandler: function(event) {
      if (!event) {
        event = window.event;
      }
      if (this.element.find($(event.target).closest('button, a, input[type="submit"]')).length) {
        return;
      }

      if (this.isFlipped) {
        this.unflip();
      } else {
        this.flip();
      }
    },

    hoverHandler: function() {
      var self = this;
      self.element.off('mouseleave.flip');

      self.flip();

      setTimeout(function() {
        self.element.on('mouseleave.flip', $.proxy(self.unflip, self));
        if (!self.element.is(":hover")) {
          self.unflip();
        }
      }, (self.setting.speed + 150));
    },

    attachEvents: function() {
      var self = this;
      if (self.setting.trigger === "click") {
        self.element.on($.fn.tap ? "tap.flip" : "click.flip", $.proxy(self.clickHandler, self));
      } else if (self.setting.trigger === "hover") {
        self.element.on('mouseenter.flip', $.proxy(self.hoverHandler, self));
        self.element.on('mouseleave.flip', $.proxy(self.unflip, self));
      }
    },

    flipChanged: function(callback) {
      this.element.trigger('flip:change');
      if (typeof callback === 'function') {
        callback.call(this.element);
      }
    },

    changeSettings: function(options, callback) {
      var self = this;
      var changeNeeded = false;

      if (options.axis !== undefined && self.setting.axis !== options.axis.toLowerCase()) {
        self.setting.axis = options.axis.toLowerCase();
        changeNeeded = true;
      }

      if (options.reverse !== undefined && self.setting.reverse !== options.reverse) {
        self.setting.reverse = options.reverse;
        changeNeeded = true;
      }

      if (changeNeeded) {
        var faces = self.frontElement.add(self.backElement);
        var savedTrans = faces.css(["transition-property", "transition-timing-function", "transition-duration", "transition-delay"]);

        faces.css({
          transition: "none"
        });

        // This sets up the first flip in the new direction automatically
        var rotateAxis = "rotate" + self.setting.axis;

        if (self.isFlipped) {
          self.frontElement.css({
            transform: rotateAxis + (self.setting.reverse ? "(-180deg)" : "(180deg)"),
            "z-index": "0"
          });
        } else {
          self.backElement.css({
            transform: rotateAxis + (self.setting.reverse ? "(180deg)" : "(-180deg)"),
            "z-index": "0"
          });
        }
        // Providing a nicely wrapped up callback because transform is essentially async
        setTimeout(function() {
          faces.css(savedTrans);
          self.flipChanged(callback);
        }, 0);
      } else {
        // If we didnt have to set the axis we can just call back.
        self.flipChanged(callback);
      }
    }

  });

  /*
   * jQuery collection methods
   */
  $.fn.flip = function(options, callback) {
    if (typeof options === 'function') {
      callback = options;
    }

    if (typeof options === "string" || typeof options === "boolean") {
      this.each(function() {
        var flip = $(this).data('flip-model');

        if (options === "toggle") {
          options = !flip.isFlipped;
        }

        if (options) {
          flip.flip(callback);
        } else {
          flip.unflip(callback);
        }
      });
    } else {
      this.each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('flip-model')) { // The element has been initiated, all we have to do is change applicable settings
          var flip = $(this).data('flip-model');

          if (options && (options.axis !== undefined || options.reverse !== undefined)) {
            flip.changeSettings(options, callback);
          }
        } else { // Init
          $(this).data('flip-model', new Flip($(this), (options || {}), callback));
        }
      });
    }

    return this;
  };

}(jQuery));

InitializeHeaderSlider();

// Trigger slide every 2 seconds
function InitializeHeaderSlider() {

  var oInterval = setInterval(function() {

    // Initialize flipper
    var oFlip = $('#FlipWrapper').flip();

    // Trigger flip toggle
    oFlip.flip('toggle');


    console.log('flipped');

  }, 2000);

}
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #CCC; /* just for demo purpose */
}

div#FlipWrapper {
  z-index: 999 !important;
  top: 38%;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateX(-3%) skew(16deg);
  position: relative;
}

div#FlipWrapper div.Wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 175px !important;
  height: 175px !important;
}

div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo {
  width: inherit !important;
  height: inherit !important;
  background-color: #241f20;
  border: 10px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute !important;
  z-index: 99;
  top: 32%;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 35px;
}

div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner>img {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(-8deg);
}

div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner p {
  color: #ffffff;
  transform: rotate(-12deg);
  line-height: 43px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 52px;
  font-family: "AmaticBold", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

div#FlipWrapper div.ShopLogo div.Inner p span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 42px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="FlipWrapper">
  <div class="ShopLogo front">
    <div class="Wrapper">
      <div id="FlipCoinFront" class="Inner valign-wrapper">
        <p>shop <span class="In"> - in - </span>shop</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ShopLogo back">
    <div class="Wrapper">
      <div id="FlipCoinBack" class="Inner valign-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't know borders where affected by their parents if the width and height is the same! (I'm aware I should have tested that before posting hehe). Only thing left to do is some basic repositioning and we're good to go!